# Files created in current shell session

Tags: shell, files

Is there a way to get list of files created in current shell session? I can track user and timestamp, but is there a direct answer?

Comment: No, you can't. Unix generally does not keep track of file creation timestamps, and files are not associated with a shell session. Could you maybe specify a bit more carefully what you're attempting to achieve? The closest you would probably get is finding files that have been _modified_ or have had their file meta information updated during the time since the shell session started.

Comment: Well, I'd like to login to remote machine via ssh and run some scripts that produces some files, that are not needed after certain time. Unfortunately, scripts don't cleanup after themselves so I need to remove those files by myself (I cannot really modify scripts).

Comment: Can you not just note down the files from the scripts and then create another script to remove the files at the end?

Comment: Or just put all the created files in a directory and delete files by age (older than 14days in the following case)  `find /bar -type f -name *.foo -mtime +14 -delete`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's about cleaning up after scripts, at least make sure your scripts create their files in `/tmp` or some place where you can clean up easily.

If you really want to track all files, use `strace -fefile ...` to see all file operations. Note, this will slow down your scripts.